# Rename localy a Fortran derived type loaded from a module

Tags: module, fortran, derived-types

I'd like to improve the readability of my Fortran codes by using OOP.
I end up with quite complex derived types, for example: `a%b%c%d%e`, defined in module `mymod`.

Now, in a subroutine I do

```
subroutine test
    use mymod, only: a
    ! lots of unrelevant stuff, especially with a%b%c%d%e.
end subroutine
```

My problem is the following: I would like to rename, in this particular subroutine, `a%b%c%d%e` to a simple `newname`.

I tested, for example: `use mymod, only: a%b%c%d%e => newname` but I a get compilation error that states:

> Error: Syntax error in USE statement

Comment: Check out the `associate` construct.

Comment: @eriktous: You should add that as a real answer, it seems to me this is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @sigma: Yeah, will do. I had little time when I wrote this, so made it into a comment to help the OP out quickly, half hoping someone else would write up a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `associate` construct to do this.

```
subroutine test
    use :: mymod, only: a
    associate(newname => a%b%c%d%e)
        ! lots of unrelevant stuff, now using newname.
    end associate
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguably a better approach is to pass the argument through the subroutine's argument list, in which case you can use any local name that you like:

```
subroutine test(a)
...
end subroutine
```

and then call

```
call subroutine test(a%b%c%d%e)
```

And, while I'm writing, when you rename an entity on a `use` statement the form is

```
local-name => use-name
```

and not, as you have it,

```
use-name => local-name
```

Comment: Thanks but this a%b%c%d%e may be used absolutely everywhere in the code. Isn't there a more "module-oriented" way?

Comment: It can't be used in a `use, only` specification, for example.